# reading key press in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently learning basic jQuery on Codecademy, and lesson 12/12 provided some code without explanation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
            // Left arrow key pressed
            case 37:
                $('img').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 0);
                break;

...
```

I understand that `keydown` is called when any key is pressed, but I don't understand why I need to include the parameter `key` in `function()`. Up until this point, I have always left it empty.

I understand that `key.which` refers to the key which the user pressed (at least according to w3schools) but if so, why do I need the `key` parameter in `function()`? At what point in the code is the user's key press actually recorded?

A google search yielded the jQuery API for event.which, which I couldn't really understand..

ALSO, this is not really related to the above question, but:

How does the compiler check for input, and does it prioritize certain events over others? Does it just go through the entire program many times per second? What happens with very large programs where the compiler needs to check for many events? For example, if I have a click event on line 123125 for a div and a hover event on line 20 for the same div, and I hover then click on that div in rapid succession, will the compiler read both events in time?

Comment: the keydown() function is the event listener for the users key press. the function inside keydown(), gets triggered on keypress to do something. so the keypress is "recorded" by calling keydown()

Comment: Please split your two question to two actual questions on the site. One question per question please.

Comment: to answer your second question - every trigger event gets recorded and then fires the associated function. if two trigger interfere with the same element, the events get queued and the compiler works at them sequentially. 
there are stop() functions to avoid this queuing for example in transitions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some thing like overloads provided by the Jquery....

means if you code does not need the information about the pressed key... You just want to be notified about the key down event... in this case you will not use "key" in the parameter like:

```
$(document).keydown(function() {});
```

but if you want to know which key is pressed then you will have to use "key" in the parameter like:

```
 $(document).keydown(function(key) {
```

And Jquery will handle this on back hand...

And No matter how many events you will register, your performance will not be effected.

As far as sequence is concerned no event will overlap any event the sequence of event firing is predefined.

Answer (score 2):

When any event occurs, JavaScript will look for all the event handlers that match the specific event.

JavaScript boasts many types of events, click, mousedown, keydown, input, onsubmit, etc.

When an event with a registered handler occurs, JavaScript will bundle all of the information about the event to a single **[Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)** object, and *pass it to the handler function* as the first argument.

Note that this is a **JavaScript object**  and not a jQuery one.

JavaScript allows you to silently omit the argument if you don't need it.

---

A **[KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)** object is an extension of the original Event object, and contains the `.which` property which contains the key code of the key which was pressed.